# apt-mirror - Changing source mirror creates new folder for downloads

Tags: 10.04, apt, mirrors, apt-mirror

I have a local Ubuntu mirror running on ubuntu 10.04 in my office which uses archive.ubuntu.com to download updates and releases. I have been running this mirror since Ubuntu's Hardy Heron release. It downloads everything under /export/ubuntu-repo1/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ folder.

Recently I came to know that the mirror in India i.e. in.archive.ubuntu.com is a lot faster for me than http://archive.ubuntu.com which is based in UK. Therefore to download latest release QUANTAL QUETZAL I configured Indian mirror in /etc/apt/mirror.list

After making this change and leaving apt-mirror to run overnight I found that it downloaded everything to a new folder called "in.archive.ubuntu.com" so now I have two folders where apt-mirror downloads updates.

/export/ubuntu-repo1/apt-mirror/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/
/export/ubuntu-repo1/apt-mirror/mirror/in.archive.ubuntu.com/

Now, since apache does not have "in.archive.ubuntu.com" configured, Ubuntu clients are unable to access QUANTAL QUETZAL release and its updates.

My question is:

Is there a way I could copy everything downloaded under "in.archive.ubuntu.com" to "archive.ubuntu.com" so all new updates of the latest release become accessible to Ubuntu clients? Secondly, Can I configure apt-mirror to download everything to archive.ubuntu.com even using Indian mirror?

Thanks a lot for your help in advance.

I Kazi

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But it seems that renaming all folders to the new mirrorsite, solves the issue. As you want to keep continuing using the in.archive.ubuntu.com mirror site, it is easier to make sure your clients can connect to the your local mirror site
In your case: 
change your 
../mirror/archive.ubuntu.com to ../mirror/in.archive.ubuntu.com
../skel/archive.ubuntu.com to ../skel/in.archive.ubuntu.com

As you already have in.archive.ubuntu.com directory, if its finished, then you only have to change your apache configuration.
Then change your apache configuration to point to the ubuntu directory within your in.archive.ubuntu.com directory. Either you use a quick and dirty method as described in http://unixrob.blogspot.nl/2012/05/create-apt-mirror-with-ubuntu-1204-lts.html. 
Or you change your apache configuration as needed. (e.g. a virtual host.)

Karel